# Is the Motor Shaft Input (LdTrq) required in the Surface Mount PMSM block (MATLAB/SIMULINK 2020a)?

Tags: matlab, simulation, matlab-deployment, simscape

I am trying to implement FOC algorithm in Simulink using the Motor Control Blockset. I want to simulate the iPower Gimbal Motor GBM2804H-100T with the Surface mount PMSM block. However, I don't understand what the LdTrq input is or how to set it up. SInce it is a motor I do not understand why a motor shaft input torque is required. Also if I am required to use this input, could I use a constant or would I need to do something else ? Please any help would be really appreciated.

Surface Mount PMSM: https://www.mathworks.com/help/mcb/ref/surfacemountpmsm.html

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with this block, but a quick glance tells me that in order to calculate al the variables in 'info', such as 'Stator phase current A', and others, you will need to have the torque on the shaft, and the Voltages across the 3 phases. From this Simulink calculates all the info

It seems that the block also gives the option of selecting 'speed'. Either way, it needs an input in order to calculate the dynamics

By the way, if you have a certain load on the motor shaft and you want to exert a torque on that load, or you want to bring that load up to a certain speed, than you can provide a torque profile as input. That is why it is called LdTrq -> Load Torque.

[image]